# How can you implement the C language with DrRacket?

Tags: c, racket

Does anyone know how to install the C language or enable it in the DrRacket?

I have installed [the C package](http://pkgs.racket-lang.org/#[c]) but I get an error every time I run my program.

The error is:

```
 ..\..\Program Files\Racket\collects\racket\system.rkt:181:19:
system*: contract violation
expected: path-string?   given: #f
```

Answer (score 5):

First off: I'm assuming that you're talking about Jay McCarthy's ["C" package](http://pkgs.racket-lang.org/#[c]) for Racket. If not, please ignore everything below.

I'm pretty sure that the problem here is that you're running this on Windows. This language level tries to run a C compiler, and Windows is ... not a system that makes it easy to run a C compiler.

I think the right answer here, sadly, is that I wouldn't expect this package to work correctly on Windows. I think the best fix is probably just for the package to signal an error on Windows.

Sorry :(.

Perhaps +jeapostrophe has something to add here?

EDIT: I took a look at the package source, and that's exactly what's going on.  I've made a pull request that should at least improve the error message a bit.